Why is M nondiagonalizable?
If M has full set of linearly independent eigenvectors, then M is diagonalizable.
M = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -2 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & -n \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & n & 0
\end{bmatrix}
The structure of M shows that it consists of blocks of the form
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -k \\
k & 0
\end{bmatrix}
So the eigenvalue for each block is $\lambda = \pm ik$. For each block, we get two linearly independent eigenvectors, corresponding to the eigenvalues $\pm ik$. Since these eigenvectors are linearly independent and M consists of n such blocks, we have 2n linearly independent eigenvectors in total. Thus, M has a full set of linearly independent eigenvectors and is diagonalizable.
However, the solution says this is nondiagonalizable. Where did I not think correctly?

Diagonalizable over which field?

@JoséCarlosSantos Whoops I think that's why, diagonalizable over complex but not real field. Thanks!
